# ¿Existe una palabra para describir esta característica humana que es muy similar al coraje en un sentido, pero muy opuesta en otro?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

"El coraje o la valentía es una virtud humana, que se puede definir como la fuerza de voluntad que puede poseer una persona para llevar adelante una acción a pesar de los impedimentos. El coraje es la habilidad de sobreponerse a dichos impedimentos y perseverar probablemente con la acción que se pretendía realizar. El coraje consiste en enfrentarse a situaciones valiosas e importantes de manera que superes el miedo a fracasar en ellas; también se entiende como la fuerza por hacer algo por alguien o por ti mismo."

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo se le puede llamar, a la característica humana, que es la fuerza de voluntad que posee una persona para enfrentar los miedos, pero no para hacer frente a situaciones valiosas o importantes (cosas buenas, con connotación positiva) sino para hacer cosas muy malas? Supongamos un asesino que arriesga su vida repetidamente superando miedos, pero en lugar de para hacer algo bueno, para matar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy difícil clasificar cuándo algo está bien o está mal. Las definiciones del diccionario difícilmente podrán entrar en hacer ese tipo de valoraciones, puesto que el hecho de que alguien mate puede ser malo para ti, pero bueno para otros.

Pongamos el ejemplo siguiente: una persona se ve forzada a alistarse obligatoriamente en el ejército para defender a su país en una guerra. Le entrenan, le dan un arma y, llegado el momento, se va a combatir al frente. Llega el momento cumbre, tiene al enemigo enfrente, odia matar, odia la violencia, pero sabe que va a ser o él o su adversario. En otras circunstancia incluso el hombre que tiene enfrente podría haber sido su amigo del alma, pero en ese instante no puede hacer cábalas. ¿Qué es lo que impulsa a esa persona a apretar el gatillo? El coraje. El coraje no necesita saber si lo que va a hacer está bien o mal, simplemente es lo que necesita para realizar la acción que no olvidará el resto de su vida.

> **[coraje](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AnqFjwv)**
>
> 1. m. Impetuosa decisión y esfuerzo del ánimo, valor.

Y si nos vamos a la definición de valor, encontramos:

> **[valor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bJeLxWG)**
>
> 8. m. Cualidad del ánimo, que mueve a acometer resueltamente grandes empresas y a arrostrar los peligros. Usado también en sentido peyorativo, denotando osadía, y hasta desvergüenza. *¿Cómo tienes valor para eso? Tuvo el valor de negarlo.*

Nótese que la definición de *valor* incluye un sentido peyorativo en el que el valor se emplea para hacer cosas negativas desde el punto de vista del hablante. En el ejemplo de la guerra:

> Tuvo el valor de apretar el gatillo para acabar con la vida de su enemigo.

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre **temeridad**. Según la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZPYqCUo):

> 1. f. Cualidad de temerario.

Lo que nos lleva a [temerario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZPYZdVx):

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Excesivamente imprudente arrostrando peligros.

Y para reforzar, los significados de [arrostrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3nshKZj):

> 1. tr. Hacer cara, resistir, sin dar muestras de cobardía, a las calamidades o peligros.
> 2. tr. Sufrir o tolerar a alguien o algo desagradable. U. t. c. intr.
> 3. prnl. Atreverse, arrojarse a batallar rostro a rostro con el contrario.

Comment: No está mal, pero un temerario no necesariamente supera los miedos para hacer el mal, puede ser simplemente un imprudente o un inconsciente, pero puede usar eso para el bien.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: es cierto, entendí la pregunta como buscando una definición amoral, sin tener connotaciones positivas, pero tampoco necesariamente con connotaciones negativas.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que una de los problemas es distinguir la "virtud" o cualidad de algo (connotaciones positivas que percibimos o que nosotros le damos a algo) y el uso que se haga de las mismas. Yo creo que se podría usar "valiente" y "coraje" en los contextos de tu pregunta. Alguien puede ser valiente, pero usar esa cualidad de una manera que no haga el mundo mejor. Se puede ser valiente e inteligente y malvado a la vez.

Ten en cuenta que el uso de "valor", dependiendo del contexto, no necesariamente refiere a una virtud.

> Tuvo el *valor* de decirme que la preparación de la fiesta fue un desastre, a pesar de que él no ayudó para nada por más que se lo pedimos.
>
> Hay que tener valor para hacer un comentario tan machista delante de un grupo de mujeres

En estos casos, tiene más de "caradura", "desvergüenza", "chulería" e incluso "desafío" que de virtud.

En cualquier caso, puestos a buscar una palabra que exprese

> Dispuesto a superar peligros para hacer algo que no beneficie a sus semejantes

(o similar) podemos usar

- [Osado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RH4I3ef) (que tiene osadía, atrevimiento)
- [Audaz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4MlGa9n)
- Atrevido
- Aventurado
- Resuelto

En realidad, las definiciones del DRAE enlazan unas con las otras, pero estos sinónimos tienen menos connotación de ser una virtud que `valor` o `coraje`.  `Audaz` puede tener un poco más de "inteligente" que las otras (o quizá solo es percepción mía) y `atrevido` y `osado` pueden ser un poco más lo que estás buscando.

Por último, tienes términos como "[bizarro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dC5eFT)" o "[corajudo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Anujf4j)", que también son sinónimos de valiente, pero son algo más "oscuros" (menos usados).